# Combine two queries in one (one by one and sorted)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table of models with columns

[image: table with two columns]

Both columns are of a varchar type that contains an array of strings.

What I need to achieve here is to get all tags separately, without dups and in specific order. First should be system_tags in alphabetical order, then tags in alphabetical order as well

```
    SELECT 
      unnest(system_tags) as tag_name 
    FROM 
      "models" 
      left join projects on projects.id = models.project_id
      where projects.is_public = true
    union 
    SELECT 
      unnest(tags) 
    FROM 
      "models" 
      left join projects on projects.id = models.project_id
      where projects.is_public = true
```

I got as far as to get all separated tags without duplications, but can I order them one by one with union?
So I can get result as on the first picture instead as it on the second

[image: wanted result]      [image: current result]

Comment: You have tagged two different DBMS. What is the actual platform you are using?

Comment: Sorry, probably misclicked mysql instead sql? Meant for postgres

Comment: Note that alphabetical order would probably sort _mytag111_ between _mytag11_ and _mytag12_...

Answer (score -1):

Use a union query to combine multiple queries into a single result. Sometimes you might want to list the records from one table or query with those from one or more other tables to form one set of records - a list with all the records from the two or more tables. This is the purpose of a union query in Access.

Comment: The original post already uses a `UNION`, so they're probably already familiar with that concept.